# How to disable click on SlidingUpPanelLayout

Tags: android

I use [Android Sliding Up Panel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel).
I need help on how to disable the Click to **collapse/expand**, and only allow the user to drag the panel. Any ideas?

Answer (score -2):

I guess you can disable the Click by adding a click listener for `setFadeOnClickListener`:

```
yourSlidingLayout.setFadeOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        // Do nothing when clicked.
      }
    });
```